# Latin translation for "It is the idea that someone/something's existence is a threat to peace that is a threat to peace"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How can I translate *"It is the idea that someone/something's existence is a threat to peace that is a threat to peace."* into Latin?
The main problems here are that I don't know how to translate the It-Cleft sentence (i.e. the
**It ... that ...** part) into Latin, and that I can't make sure whether or not Latin has the Appositive Clause (the **idea that ...** part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am concerned it does not work in the way that it works in English. A translation's duty is to give the meaning of the sentence rather than offering a translation exactly word by word, hence I would probably go for something like:

Thinking someone/something's existence is a threat to peace is itself a threat (to peace):

> cōgitāre aliquem/aliquid exīstentiam minātionem contrā pācem esse,
> ipsum minātio est (contrā pācem).

**Explanation of using accusative** - For example, when you wish to say "I think (that) this pencil is nice" the construction of the sentence in Latin would be "cōgitō hanc graphidem(graphis, graphidis, f.) bonam esse".

Comment: I like the overall construction, but I believe "threat" in the original English essentially means "danger," whereas *minatio* is a threat as an action. Possibly something like *paci detrimento esse* would work better.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I see what you mean, but since "thinking" is an action, I believe it is still compliant - like the difference between an act `actus` and action`actio`.  Hmm, something to search about. Thank you for your addition!

Comment: Also to consider using *alicujus* instead of *aliquem*. Like the English, I guess in the Latin the genitive is to be preferred here. though I could not find classical examples of *existentia*

Comment: @d_e I was going for "to be an existence" like: aliquem esse existentiam. In terms of existentia being derived from existens: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/existentia